# JSON Data inside Raphael

Tags: json, raphael

I have JSON data

```
var scores = 
    "zerozero": {
        "srl": 36.465,
        "phr": 32.933,
        "seo": 25.988,
        "hd": 47.106,
        "root": 35.623
    };
```

I am looking to use this JSON data to create a Raphael Path

Desiered outout:
`graph.path("M18,222.25L55,223.3L92").attr({stroke:"RGB(217,31,53)", "stroke-width":2});`

the 222.25 should come from some maths:

```
350-(zerozero.srl*3.5)
```

Anyway of placing this math into the path?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Write a function to map the JSON data to a path, and then just feed it to a new Raphael path object. You've got some weird syntax in the `zerozero` object you need to fix.

```
var graph = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 500);

var zerozero = {
        "srl": 36.465,
        "phr": 32.933,
        "seo": 25.988,
        "hd": 47.106,
        "root": 35.623
    };

var order = ["root", "srl", "phr", "seo", "hd"];

var path = "M" + order.map(function(d) { return 350-(zerozero[d]*3.5); }).join("L");

graph.path("M18,222.25L55,223.3L92").attr({stroke:"RGB(217,31,53)", "stroke-width":2});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HMJkT/